# Notepad++ like editor with with macrosed text replacements for faster coding

Tags: editor, notepad++

Is there any editor or add-on/plugin which replaces some keywords with prepared snippets in place of written keyword.

For example i'm typing key1 and it's instantly or after a space is replaced with snippet that is assigned to this keyword.

I saw some tutorial from Jeffrey Way long ago, but can't find it now. :s

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

[FingerText](https://github.com/erinata/FingerText/) for Notepad++ pretty much does what you want.
Just use Tab after typing in the keyword you set up for the snippet, and it'll replace it with the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/) editor has a *template* feature that does exactly this. A template is a keyword with an associated code snippet and typing in a keyword followed by the *space key* results in the keyword being replaced by the associated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> Try installing AutoHotkey version 1.1.19.03 or greater.
>
> One thing it can do is look for sequences of keyboard characters and replace them with other sequences on the fly. As soon as it sees a sequence it will replace it. No activating character is required.
>
> To set up the replacement definitions:
>   Right click on the Desktop 
>   `New` 
>   `AutoHotkey Script`
>    This will create a template for
>   your script with the name `New AutoHotkey Script.ahk`
>    Edit `New AutoHotkey Script.ahk` with Notepad++
>    Put your key snippet lines at
>   the end, like so:
>
> `:*:key1::snippet for key1`
>   `:*:key2::snippet this time for key2`
>
> Save As `My Snippet definitions.ahk`
>
> To invoke it: Double click `My Snippet definitions.ahk`
>   You can control AutoHotkey by right clicking on its icon on the taskbar.